# hover is not detecting on element

Tags: jquery

I've something as below code:

```
$('#element').hover(function(){
    //do something
},function(){
    if($('#menu').is(':hover')){
        console.log('menu is hovered');
    } else{
        console.log('menu is not hovered');
    }
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gtdevdh0/)

When mouse is out from `element div` it should detect if the menu is hovered or not.

The code works fine in chrome but not in firefox.

Comment: no it doesn't. first move mouse into element then move mouse into menu then you'll see it's loggin menu is not hovered

Comment: Hmm, remove "Firebug Lite 1.4.0" dependency.

Comment: I was working with my site locally and seemed bug so I've posted this question. There's no problem with firebug lite

Comment: It looks like you're running into an issue with whitespace (if you move your mouse from the red block to menu, you'll see the cursor change). That pixel of whitespace is when your hover event triggers. Wrapping the if statement in a timeout might help. http://jsfiddle.net/gtdevdh0/7/

Comment: No, I've no gap but setTimeout seems working...

Comment: You're right! My bad. There is no gap!

Comment: But using setTimeout I'm facing Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined in chrome and type error: ownerDocument is not defined in firefox (not with fiddle but with my site)

Comment: It works if you remove firebug lite. http://jsfiddle.net/gtdevdh0/10/ check this out